# How can flag if column values had increase/decrease in last n months in time series data frame in python?

Tags: pandas, time-series

I am working with customer data and need to flag customers who had decrease or increase in salary in last 6 and 12 months?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not having a ton of information, let's assume your timeseries data is set up so each row consists of monthly data. i.e row 1 is January data, row 2 is February, etc.

Here is an implementation https://www.statology.org/pandas-difference-between-rows/

Then you can use apply to check each row in the `delta` column and if it is positive return the value `increase` otherwise return the value `decrease`. You can probably use lambda for this.

My syntax may be a little off but this is the general idea to return a boolean flag.

`df['flag']= df['delta'].apply(lambda x: x>0)`